# Как обрабатывать перелистывание viewPager

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

Я работаю с API,с которого получаю данные. Эти данные привязаны к дням недели. Я инициализирую viewPager данными на текущий день. 
Мне нужно реализовать такую функциональность : если я перелистываю pager влево,то получаю вчерашний день и соответствующие данные. если я перелистываю его вправо, то должен вернуться на день вперед, если он меньше текущего дня.

В данный момент я использую нечто наподобие :

```
int count = 0;
public String  getPreviousDate(int count){
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -count);
return dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()) }
```

Этот метод я использую в методе getContent(),который делает запрос к серверу, получает и парсит JSON. (стринговое значение даты я вставляю в конец Url,по которому обращаюсь к серверу)
Относительно скроллинга viewPager на данный момент я использую подобный подход :

```
mViewPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        count++;
        if (count >= 0) {
            getContent();
        } ...
```

Но это не совсем то , что мне требуется. Как корректно реализовать необходимую мне функциональность? Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему вам нужен `ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener`, назначаемый в качестве аргумента метода `addOnPageChangeListener` класса `ViewPager`

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position)
    {
        super.onPageSelected(position);
        Log.d("someString", "page " + position + " selected");
    }
});
```